# FI-WARE Identity Management - Integration with 3rd party providers

Tags: fiware

I read about the FI-Ware Identity Management GE.
I understand it acts as an OAuth2 Identity Provider enabling users to log in into applications using their FI-Ware site credentials.
The FI-Ware catalog site states this about the IdM :

> In addition to providing a native login, IdM supports the integration
>   of multiple 3rd party authentication providers. Foremost, it supports
>   in a first step the configuration of preferred identity providers
>   through the administrators. The use of 3rd party IdMs lowers the entry
>   barriers for a native user to register, since the user can link to
>   her/his preferred IdM and use this account for authentication.

However, I could not find an explanation how this can be done.
Can anyone help ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IdM doesn't support authentication with other IdP's. What that paragraph explains is that developers can use third party authentication in THEIR services using other IdP such us Google, Facebook or Keyrock. So what IdM supports is to allow other services to login using IdM authentication.
BR

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I still have a hard time grasping it. Can you provide a more detailed explanation or an illustration perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: You will find an specific course explaining how to do so in FIWARE Lab academy:
https://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=79
Specifically in Lesson 3